# libfuse and git: locking does not work due to chmod

Tags: git, fuse

The files that I want to gittify (?) are on a file share on a NAS. `git init` was fine.

Now I'm trying to add a remote with git and I get an error:

```
$ git remote add origin git@git.server.com:base/my-project.git 
error: chmod on /home/user/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not supported
```

If I try manually I get also the error as expected

```
$ chown user.user .git
chown: changing ownership of ‘.git’: Function not implemented
```

Note that

```
$ ls -la .
rwx------. 1 user user  108047 20 ago 10.18 .fuse_hidden0000000c00000001
-rwx------. 1 user user   50737  9 ago 21.14 .fuse_hidden0000009900000001
drwx------. 1 user user       0  2 set 20.45 .git
-rwx------. 1 user user      60  2 set 20.28 .gitignore
```

That is: the user is already correct.

A solution would be to work in /home/user that is a normal ext4, but that is exactly what I do not want.

I tried in `.gitconfig` with

```
[core]
    fileMode = false
```

but no positive result.

Question:

How do I prevent git from using chmod?

A solution would also be to edit `.git/config` manually, but this is also not a nice solution. **EDIT** This solution works, but I get by push a series of errors

**EDIT** I could have titled this question as *"How to prevent git changing the ownership of files?"* , because exactly that is what it is trying to do twice on `.git/config.lock` by pushing (and other commands as add remote)

Answer (score 0):

I see the NAS has a Unix/Linux shell. However,  what is the file system on which your /home/user/my project is? Could it be ntfs or so. Then the following might help or tell you why the operation is not supported:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: The shell is of the PC I'm working on, not the one of the NAS. I know that chmod is not supported, therefore I asked "How do I prevent git from using chmod?"